# State being overridden in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  <form onChange = {handleFilterChange}>
    <select name="movie">
      <option value="default">Please choose a movie</option>
      {state.data.map(movie => (<option value={movie.title}>{movie.title}</option>))}
    </select>
    <select name="species">
      {state.appliedFilters.movie !== undefined ? [...new Set(species)].map(specie => (<option value={specie}>{specie}</option>)):
      (<option value="default">Please select a movie first)</option>) }
    </select>
  </form>
```

I have this form above and an onChange function:

```
  const handleFilterChange = (e) => {
    if(e.target.value === 'default' && state.appliedFilters !== undefined){
      setState({...state ,appliedFilters : {}});
    }else{
      setState({...state, appliedFilters:{[e.target.name] : e.target.value}})
    }
  }
```

When i apply a movie filter and then i make a change to the species select the movie filter goes away and the species only stays.

Comment: The reason why it goes away is because you're saying `appliedFilters: {}`, so you're resetting it.

Comment: @goto1 I only reset it conditional

Comment: Then your `else` is incorrect, you should update your `appliedFilters` object rather than replacing it with `{[e.target.name]: e.target.value}` - `this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, appliedFilters: {...prevState.appliedFilters, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }))`. But I feel like your `if` statement is also incorrect, so that might cause issues as well.

Comment: @goto1 the if statment was correct its suposed to clear all filters when the condition is met. ``appliedFilters: {...prevState.appliedFilters`` this helped tho

Answer (score 1):

You've set the onChange handler on the `<form>` and not on the `<select>` so the `event.target` and `event.target.value` is not what you intended (it's the form and not the select).

Move the onChange to the movie `<select>`:

```
 <form>
    <select name="movie" onChange={handleFilterChange}>
      <option value="default">Please choose a movie</option>
      {state.data.map(movie => (<option value={movie.title}>{movie.title}</option>))}
    </select>
    <select name="species">
      {state.appliedFilters.movie !== undefined ? [...new Set(species)].map(specie => (<option value={specie}>{specie}</option>)):
      (<option value="default">Please select a movie first)</option>) }
    </select>
  </form>
```